# Working with checkboxes in asp.net mvc3 plus mass update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Currently I am attempting to create a mass update based on a series of checkboxes. I can't seem to find the correct way to do it using the entity framework.

I am using ASP.Net 4 with MVC3 and Razor.

Here is the code I have so far.

### View Page (Working Properly)

```
@model List<LeagueCounters.Models.champion>
<form name="setFree id="setFree" method="POST" action="/Champion/SetFree">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.isFree == true)
        {
           <input type="checkbox" id="@item.id" checked="checked" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)  
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="checkbox" id="@item.id" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)
        }
    }
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
```

### Controller (Errors)

```
[HttpPost, Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SetFree(FormCollection fcMain)
{
     var sortedList = from c in _db.champions
                      orderby c.name
                      select c;
     int counter = 0;
     foreach (champion champ in sortedList)
     {
         if (fcMain[counter].Contains("true"))
            champ.isFree = true;
         else
            champ.isFree = false;

         _db.champions.Attach(champ);
         _db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(champ, EntityState.Modified);

         counter++;
     }

     _db.SaveChanges();

     return View();
}
```

### Errors

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

### Question

How do I properly cycle through the checkboxes in the controller? And will my mass update code work once I get to that point?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ignoring any other issues for now, your `fcMain[counter]` collection is 0-based, but you are starting the index/counter at 1. That means you will run past the last entry. It is of course dangerous to assume your data collection is the same length as the number of checkboxes if multiple uses use that site.

Comment: I did change this to zero with the same results.

Comment: Have you debugged the lines of code and viewed how many entries vs how many controls? Indexing direct into `fcMain` with an untested index is the most likely point of failure.

Comment: can you compare the count of the form collection with the count of the model collection.. and are you using IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that only the checked checkboxes are posted to the server. So you can't expect all of your checkbox keys to be present in the form collection. To workaround this behavior `Html.CheckBoxFor` creates an additional hidden field with checkbox so the result could be read on the server side. I am not sure how would you use strongly typed helper here because you are rendering data in a loop. I think you can have a look at this [google search](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=primary%20vs%20candidate%20key&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&aq=f&oq=primary%20vs%20candidate%20key&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&sclient=psy-ab&q=editing%20a%20variable%20length%20list%20asp.net%20mvc%203&oq=editing%20variable%20len&gs_l=serp.11.1.0i30l4.19294803.19298745.0.19301011.20.14.0.6.6.2.662.4038.2-11j0j2j1.14.0...0.0...1c.u_XXBrc6ro0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e64b366eb07673f&biw=1366&bih=667&pf=p&pdl=300)

Answer (score 0):

i think this line

```
fcMain[counter].Contains("true")
```

is causing the errors..are you using some kind of constraint selection(`Where`) when providing the model to the View
also you should add a hidden field after every checkbox by doing

```
<input type="hidden" value="false" id="@item.id" name="@item.id"/>
```

this way all the checkboxes will be submitted successfully
and you will have to *split the values* and *take the first value* thats present on the server side.
or you can skip both and directly use `@Html.Checkbox(item.Id,item.isFree)` this way the code will be cleaner and no need to manually add additional `Hidden Input` will be added automatically by the *Razor engine*
there are also some other improvements you can do to keep code `DRY`. 
change this

```
if (item.isFree == true)
{
   <input type="checkbox" id="@item.id"  checked="checked" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)  
}
else
{
   <input type="checkbox" id="@item.id" /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)
}
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@item.id" name="@item.id" @(!Item.isFree?"checked=\"checked\":\"\"") /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.displayName)
```

and i dont think you need these

```
_db.champions.Attach(champ);
_db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(champ, EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestions although the issues still exist :(